How to create index in anzo graph?
When attempting to create an index using the cypher query, in bolt CLI provided with anzograph setup an exception is thrown:
CREATE INDEX person_index FOR (n:person) ON (n.name)


Error - at line 1 column 13 near 'INDEX': Syntax error - syntax error.

How to create indexes in anzograph using bolt protocol or SPARQL?
Also if not, does anzograph creates indexes automatically?

According to the blog, there are no indexes to create and maintain, AnzoGraph DB handles all of that for you.
Ref link -https://blog.cambridgesemantics.com/anzograph-db-benchmarking-guide

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
